# Kotlin + let method + this keyword

Tags: kotlin

Venkat in his book Programming in Kotlin on page 237 explains the difference between the fluent methods also(), apply(), let() and run()

But the code listed doesn't compile.

Specifically these two calls: the compiler says `"'this' is not defined in this context"`

```
val result1 = str.let { arg ->
    print(String.format(format, "let", arg, this, result))
    result
}
println(String.format("%-10s", result1))

val result2 = str.also { arg ->
    print(String.format(format, "also", arg, this, result))
    result
}
println(String.format("%-10s", result2))
```

So my question is: does the let() and also() support the 'this' keyword.

Comment: They don't. See [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#function-selection). Also you may take a look at signatures of  [let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) and [apply](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html), to see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source function of `let`:

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block(this)
}
```

you'll see it takes a lambda that has one argument. So to use that argument you can use `it`.

If in a `let` you call `this`, it'll refer to the scope of the class that the function is called into:

```
class Clazz {

  fun function() {
     something.let {
        // `this` refers to class scope, so `this` is a Clazz
        // `it` refers to the something itself
     }
  }
}
```

Same thing for `also`.

The difference between `also` and `let` is how they return. `let` returns what the block returns and `also` will return the object itself, and also `let` uses a lambda as it's argument, so the parameter is accessible using `it`, while `also` uses *lambda receiver* which makes the parameter accessible as `this`.

**TL;DR**

In `let`, the keyword `this` will refer to the class it is into. So if it's not in  a class, this will refer to nothing.

Comment: Mmm.  Also worth mentioning that binding the receiver to `it` instead of `this` is the main difference between `also()` and `apply()`, and between `let()` and `run()`.

Comment: FOr more clarification in kotlin android:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/kotlin-scope-functions-b84e37644d32